# Be able to use NOT (complement) for a user search

Tags: feature-request, search

You can use `-foobar` to search for posts that do not contain the text "foobar". You can use `-[foobar]` to search for posts that are not tagged with tag `foobar`.

It does not seem possible to exclude questions and answers posted by a specific user (is it?). How about making that possible?

Suppose I want to see questions or answers or both that have given tags and contain given content, but I want to exclude posts by myself (or by some other user).  Couldn't this be useful? Possible?

Comment: @shadowwizard: It's not the same question. But the answer you just added to that question is an answer to this question. Contrast the other answer to that question, which, like that question, is about querying for users *other than the current user*, not about querying for users other than a specific arbitrary user. This question, which you closed, includes that question, but not vice versa. Likewise, your answer to that question.

Comment: I still think those two requests better be merged, but not sure enough to use hammer. Reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I agree they should be merged. It's fine that your answer to that question answers the more useful, more general question. But it would be better still if that question were framed in the more general terms. I definitely agree that there is no sense keeping two questions for what is essentially only one.